# Chart js radar hovercolorbackground not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colors, chart.js

I was able to create a great radar chart with Chart js. My only problem is that the datasets attribute hoverBackgroundColor is not making any affect.
Here's my code:

```
chosen = [[5.2,0,1,9,11],[5.1,2,4,9,7],[5.1,2,2,9,8]] 
playerNames= ['Henderson','Baldock','Stevens']

function createRadarComparison(chosen, playerNames) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var borderColors = ['#ff82827d', '#82ff917d', '#fdff827d','#b882ff7d']
    var colors = ['#ff828252', '#82ff8c52', '#fdff8252', '#b882ff52' ];
    datasetdata = []
    for (var i = 0; i < chosen.length; i++) {
        datasetdata[i] = {
            label: playerNames[i],
            data: chosen[i],
            backgroundColor: colors[i],
            hoverBackgroundColor: colors[i],
            borderColor: borderColors[i],
            pointBorderColor: "#fff",
            pointBackgroundColor: borderColors[i],
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
        }
    }
    var config = {
        type: 'radar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Price', 'Goals', 'Assits', 'Clean Sheets', 'Bonus'],
            datasets: datasetdata
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
                labels: {
                    "fontSize": 10,
                }
            },
            scale: {
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    display: false
                }
            },
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
        }
    };
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
}
```

Here's the image of the chart
[image]

I am expecting the color of the whole dataset area to change on hover, but nothing changes. Appreciate your help

Comment: can you share the `chosen, playerNames` or please add a working fiddle

Comment: chosen = [[5.2,0,1,9,11],[5.1,2,4,9,7],[5.1,2,2,9,8]] playerNames=['Henderson','Baldock','Stevens'] It's not the exact data from the example, but same format

Comment: myChart is a canvas tag object

Comment: I had done some search and found that `hoverBackground` will not work in radar chart, in all other chart it will work ( I guess, i had only checked bar chart ). This is my search result, others may get a solution :)